# Getting callback query from telegram inline buttons

Tags: python, telegram

I am new to telegram inline bot. I have no clue how I can retrieve the callback function of telegram's inlinekeyboardbuttons. Would be forever greatful if someone can explain this to me how I could retrieve user response.

```
def options(update, context):
button_list = []
for each in ["yes", "no"]:
    button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(each, callback_data=each))
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(button_list))
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                         text="Option Selected:",
                         reply_markup=reply_markup)

def build_menu(buttons, n_cols=1, header_buttons=None, footer_buttons=None):
"""
Returns a list of inline buttons used to generate inlinekeyboard responses

:param buttons: `List` of InlineKeyboardButton
:param n_cols: Number of columns (number of list of buttons)
:param header_buttons: First button value
:param footer_buttons: Last button value
:return: `List` of inline buttons
"""
menu = [buttons[i:i + n_cols] for i in range(0, len(buttons), n_cols)]
if header_buttons:
    menu.insert(0, header_buttons)
if footer_buttons:
    menu.append(footer_buttons)
return menu
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: you can't retrive `callback`. You can only assign `callback` to buttons and telegram will run this `callback` when you press button. And if you want to access some value from this function then you have to put value in global variable. OR you have to run all code directly inside `callback` and use this value directly in `callback`

Comment: [Telebot: how to retrieve InlineKeyboardButton callback data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977318/telebot-how-to-retrieve-inlinekeyboardbutton-callback-data)

Comment: what module do you use `telegram`, `telebot` or other?

Comment: I used the telegram module

Comment: If I would like to assign callback to buttons, do I write it in the callback_data=...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `CallbackQueryHandler` to assing `function` to `data`

If you use pattern `.*` then it will get all data in one function

```
def handle_callback_query(update, context):
    print(update.callback_query.data)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
                             text='[handle_callback_query] callback data: ' + update.callback_query.data)

dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(handle_callback_query, pattern='.*'))
```

You can also use pattern to assing different functions

```
def query_yes(update, context):
    print(update.callback_query.data)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
                             text='[query_yes] callback data: ' + update.callback_query.data)

def query_no(update, context):
    print(update.callback_query.data)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
                             text='[query_no] callback data: ' + update.callback_query.data)

dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(query_yes, pattern='^yes$'))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(query_no,  pattern='^no$'))
```

---

Minimal working example.

```
import os
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

# --- init ---

TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')

updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# --- commands ---

def options(update, context):
    button_list = []
    for each in ["yes", "no"]:
        button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(each, callback_data=each))
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(button_list))
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                             text="Option Selected:",
                             reply_markup=reply_markup)
    
def build_menu(buttons, n_cols=1, header_buttons=None, footer_buttons=None):
    """
    Returns a list of inline buttons used to generate inlinekeyboard responses
    
    :param buttons: `List` of InlineKeyboardButton
    :param n_cols: Number of columns (number of list of buttons)
    :param header_buttons: First button value
    :param footer_buttons: Last button value
    :return: `List` of inline buttons
    """
    menu = [buttons[i:i + n_cols] for i in range(0, len(buttons), n_cols)]
    if header_buttons:
        menu.insert(0, header_buttons)
    if footer_buttons:
        menu.append(footer_buttons)
    return menu
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('options', options))

# --- one function for all data ---

def handle_callback_query(update, context):
    print(update.callback_query.data)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
                             text='[handle_callback_query] callback data: ' + update.callback_query.data)

#dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(handle_callback_query, pattern='.*'))

# --- different functions for different data ---

def query_yes(update, context):
    print(update.callback_query.data)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
                             text='[query_yes] callback data: ' + update.callback_query.data)

def query_no(update, context):
    print(update.callback_query.data)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
                             text='[query_no] callback data: ' + update.callback_query.data)

dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(query_yes, pattern='^yes$'))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(query_no,  pattern='^no$'))

# --- start ---

print('Starting ...')    
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```